# What do Facebook do with phone numbers?

Tags: facebook

I give Facebook my phone nummber and so far I've only known three purpose of this: log in, text me password when I forget (security) and find my friend by phone number when I install its app on my phone. Are there any other purposes of using my phone number by Facebook?

Comment: Do mean officially or unofficially?

Comment: Both. You can also tell me the purposes that they haven't deployed, but they can, or in potential.

Comment: Well.... think about, what facebook is making money with and who might have a copy of its data and than think about terms like tracking down somebody and remembering "If you're not paying for the product, you are the product."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some Facebook phone number usages:

1. It sends alert messages to you regarding the birthdays of your
   friends.
2. You can wish them a happy birthday a using text message. That means you can
   comment on your friend's wall without Internet access, simply by replying to the
   birthday alert message.
3. Find your friend's location.
4. Helps in recovering your password.
5. If someone comments on your pic or post it sends you an alert by text message.

I guess this is a nice feature for everyone. I mean if you are offline then you can still get updates from your account and friends. That's amazing.